# How can i load 100 image to ram in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have two slide bars each one have 9 steps in total i have around 100 different choice
I need to show an image on the screen based on these two numbers
**The problem is** that it take a while to upload the photo "Blink effect"
Is there any way to make it much faster?

I think i can put the whole images in the ram.

They are about 10 MB

note : I need two slide ,  because each number has different meaning

```
Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/${firstSlideValue.toInt()}${secondSlideValue.toInt()}.png'),),
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have it locally? If not, you can use https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image lib

Comment: I want it to run faster ,isn't locale faster than cached network ?

Comment: If you use cached network it will download images only first time, and use local storage (sqlite) (by default i think it's for 7 days, but you can configure that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gaplessPlayback=true
```

Whether to continue showing the old image (true), or briefly show nothing (false), when the image provider changes.
I just start to show the old image until the new one is completely uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a list of asset paths (images) that you want to load, and iterate over it passing the path to `rootBundle.load(assetPath);` in the initState of your page. And then create the image from bytes with MemoryImage:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

List<String> assetsPath = [...];

initState() async {
List<Image> images = [];
  for(int i=0; i<assetsPath.length; i++){
     var data = await rootBundle.load(assetsPath[i]);
     var image = Image(image: MemoryImage(data.buffer.asUint8List()));
     images.add(image);
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you put await inside the initStaate

Comment: I edited the example. You need to put the `async` after the parenthesis.

Comment: State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.

Comment: I try to put it inside a function and called from the init state it works but i still have the blink issue

Comment: You get this error at compilation time or at runtime? For me doesn't appear this message at compilation time.

Comment: I don't know exactly how the transition between images should work while the slide changes the values, but perhaps with separated files will continuing blinking. Another approach could be an animation controlled by the slider, or even using CustomPaint in a way to merge the images into a single file to avoid the redrawing of each image.

Comment: thinking about the animation i found gaplessPlayback=true Whether to continue showing the old image (true), or briefly show nothing (false), when the image provider changes. i just start to show the old image until the new one is completely uploaded

Comment: Nice. And it work as you expect? If yes, i believe you can answer your own question and put how do you solved.